# Understanding the proof that specific sequence does not have limit

Tags: limits, analysis, proof-explanation

In mathematical analysis book, there is example of sequence $a_n$: $1$, $0$, $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{1}{3}$, $\frac{2}{3}$, $\frac{1}{4}$, $\frac{3}{4}$, $...$

Odd numbers are part of sequence: $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$, $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n = 0$

Even numbers are part of sequence: $a_n = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$, $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n = 1$

Assuming since two subsequences have two different limits, whole sequence cannot have limit.

This one is clear to me, but where I am lost is explanation or an attempt to find that $\epsilon_0\in\mathbb{R}$ exists:

$$|a_\tilde{n} - a| \geq \epsilon_0$$

i.e. there exists least one $\epsilon_0\in\mathbb{R}$ disproving definition of limit:

$$|a_n - a| < \epsilon$$

for $a,\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}$, $a$ is limit of sequence $a_n$, $\forall n > n_0(\epsilon)$; $n,n_0\in\mathbb{N}$.

To show that sequence does not have limit, there is first proposition that for $\epsilon_0$, where for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exist $\tilde{n} > n, \tilde{n}\in\mathbb{N}$ such as $|a_\tilde{n} - a| \geq \epsilon_0$, we choose number for $\epsilon_0$:

$$\epsilon_0 = \frac{1}{2}\max(|a|, |a - 1|)$$

For 1st assumption $|a - 1| \geq |a|$, because:

$$a_{2k} = 1 - \frac{1}{k} \quad \textrm{and} \quad \frac{1}{k} \to 0$$

there exists $k_0(\epsilon_0)\in\mathbb{N}$, where for $k > k_0(\epsilon_0)$ is always:
$$|a_{2k} - 1| < \epsilon_0, k\in\mathbb{N}$$

and therefore:

$$|a_{2k} - a| = |a_{2k} - 1 + (1 - a)| \geq |1 - a| - |a_{2k} - 1| \geq 2\epsilon_0 - \epsilon_0 = \epsilon_0$$

(let's call this inequality $A$)

Therefore for any $n$ therefore exists $ñ$ as even number, which has to satisfy following conditions:

$$ñ > n \quad \textrm{and} \quad ñ > 2k_0(\epsilon_0)$$

For example:

$$ñ = 2\max(n, k_0(\epsilon_0))$$

Then:

$$a_{2k}\in \langle1 - \epsilon_0, 1\rangle, k > k_0(\epsilon_0)$$

and therefore difference between $a_\tilde{n}$ and $a$ has to be at least $\epsilon_0$.

For 2nd assumption $|a - 1| \leq |a|$ would turn out by analogy, that $a$ has to be different to at least $|a|/2$ members of $a_{2k - 1}$ for $k$ big enough.

---

My question is, or rather I am stuck on how we got to the inequality $A$ in the first place based on previous assumptions and from that rest of assumptions that seem to stem from it.

---

I am sharing photos as well as link to pdf source for this example (in Czech language):

[image: one]
[image: two]

[https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~halas/MA/MA1/kopacek_-_mat._analyza_nejen_pro_fyziky_1.pdf](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ehalas/MA/MA1/kopacek_-_mat._analyza_nejen_pro_fyziky_1.pdf)

---

PS: Let me know if something there is not clear, I will try to make it more understandable if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every $\epsilon_0<1/2$ will do. Indeed, if there was an $a$ and an $n_0$ such that $|a_n-a| \le \epsilon_0$ for all $n>n_0$, then for $k>n_0$ we have
$|1-1/k-a|<\epsilon_0$ and $|1/k-a|<\epsilon_0$. By the triangle inequality, this implies that $|1-2/k|<2\epsilon_0$ which fails to hold for large $k$ if $\epsilon_0<1/2$.

Comment: I understand that |1−1/−| < 0 is from even subsequence, and |1/−| < 0 from odd subsequence, but how did you manage to apply triangle inequality here, to get |1−2/|<20? Could you elaborate in more detail, where and how this triangle inequality is applied? Thanks.

Comment: $|1 - 2/k| = |(1 - 1/k - a) + (a - 1/k)| \leq |1 - 1/k - a| + |a - 1/k|$ and $|a - 1/k| = |1/k - a|$

Comment: Actually this is much easier to understand than presented in the book. Thanks!